# Email To Salesforce - Activity logs to wrong Opportunities

Tags: opportunitycontactrole, emailtosalesforce

**Email to Salesforce** feature allows us to capture any Email sent from external email applications and log those under Opportunities(other objects too but here we're talking only for Opportunities). In order to do this, we have the **Acceptance Email Address** and the **Email to Salesforce address**. We have to send the Email from the Email Address mentioned in **Acceptance Email Address** and BCC/CC the **Email to Salesforce address**.

So as [per Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_my_email_2_sfdc.htm&type=5),

> If you configure Email to Salesforce to associate emails to matching opportunities, Salesforce searches the To and CC fields for the email addresses of your contacts. If contacts are found, Salesforce saves the email to the Activity History related list on all open opportunities, as long as the contact is assigned a contact role on the opportunity.

Now, what is happening is that if we send the email to a contact's Email Address, who has Contact Roles in two totally different open Opportunities, it will link the Email Activity to both the Opportunities.

This feels wrong to me or I am clueless that it is okay for Opportunity to have other Opportunities' Email activity logged under it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the email is an interaction with a Contact so it is not surprising that Salesforce opts to post the activity to all open Opportunities with OpportunityContactRole junction(s) to the matching Contact (on email address).

It isn't scanning the email body trying to ascertain which "opportunity" is being discussed nor is it evaluating fields in the Opportunity to decide which one is "better" (like a more advanced stage).

Should you desire a more sophisticated algorithm to assign the activities, you could consider vendor solutions such as Groove that [employ sophisticated algos to make matching decisions](https://help.groove.co/en/articles/999034-configuring-email-and-calendar-sync).

*I'm not an employee of Groove but our org did adopt this product recently*

Or, you could after the fact use a Flow or trigger to remove the activities from the less-relevant Opportunities using your own heuristics.

Comment: Ty @cropredy, I will surely check that out. Salesforce does provide an option for Relating 'Emails to Specific Records' and also an Unresolved Items list where these all activities go and we can manually assign them to records.